# ¿Cómo ponerle nombre traido desde una base de datos a un PDF generado con FPDF?

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

Estoy intentando ponerle un nombre a un archivo pdf, pero quiero que el nombre sea traido desde una base de datos MySQL para que se vea más personalizado.

Lo estoy intentando de esta forma,

```
<?php
include_once "AcademiaModel.php";

require "../Template/plantillaPDF.php";


$id = $_GET['id'];

//function GenerarReportePDF(){

    $academia = DatosAcademiaModel($id);
    $estudiantes = DatosRegistroEstuModel();


    $pdf = new PDF("P", "mm", "Letter");
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    //$pdf -> SetMargins(20,20,20); Margenes de la hora left,top,right
    $pdf -> AddPage();

    $pdf -> SetFont("Arial", "B", 12);
    //$pdf -> Cell(95,5,"Nombre",1,0,"C");
    //$pdf -> Cell(95,5,"Total a pagar",1,0,"C");
    $pdf -> Ln(5);

    while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($academia)){
        $pdf -> SetFont("Arial", "", 12);
        $pdf -> Cell(95,5,"Nombre de la academia: " . $item['NOMBRE_ACA'],0,0,"C");
        $pdf -> Cell(95,5,"Monto total a pagar: " .$item['TOTAL_PAGAR_ACADEMIA'],0,0,"C"); 
        $pdf -> Ln(10);
    }
    $pdf -> SetFont("Arial", "B", 12);
    $pdf -> Cell(100,5,"Nombre",1,0,"C");
    $pdf -> Cell(30,5,"Cedula",1,0,"C");
    $pdf -> Cell(20,5,"Eventos",1,0,"C");
    $pdf -> Cell(40,5,"Monto a pagar",1,0,"C");
    $pdf -> Ln(5);

    while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($estudiantes)){
        $pdf -> SetFont("Arial", "", 9);
        $pdf -> Cell(100,5,$datos['NOMBRE_ATLETA'],1,0,"C");
        $pdf -> Cell(30,5,$datos['CEDULA_ATLETA'],1,0,"C"); 
        $pdf -> Cell(20,5,$datos['EVENTOS'],1,0,"C"); 
        $pdf -> Cell(40,5,$datos['MONTO_A_PAGAR'],1,0,"C"); 
        $pdf -> Ln(5);
    }

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($academia);
    
    $pdf -> Output("Reporte".$row['NOMBRE_ACA'].".pdf", "D");
```

Este es el model

```
function DatosAcademiaModel(){

    $instancia = AbrirBaseDatos();
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $academia = $instancia -> query("CALL SP_SACARMONTO_ACADEMIA($id);");

    CerrarBaseDatos($instancia);

    return $academia;
}
```

Pero me da un error que dice,

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de llaves\Sistema-llaves\SistemaLlaves 1.1.1\Model\reporte.php on line 49
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de llaves\Sistema-llaves\SistemaLlaves 1.1.1\fpdf\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de llaves\Sistema-llaves\SistemaLlaves 1.1.1\fpdf\fpdf.php(1060): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de llaves\Sistema-llaves\SistemaLlaves 1.1.1\fpdf\fpdf.php(1012): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de llaves\Sistema-llaves\SistemaLlaves 1.1.1\Model\reporte.php(49): FPDF->Output('D', 'Reporte.pdf') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de llaves\Sistema-llaves\SistemaLlaves 1.1.1\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 271

Comment: Si el valor es de tipo NULL entonces revisa la consulta (que no sabemos cual es), pues podria ser que no tuviera resultados y de ahí el error.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta, si en efecto la consulta si trae datos porque ya la probé haciendo un echo, lo que yo creo que esta mal es porque mysqli_fetch_array necesita de un while pero no estoy seguro.

Comment: No, no necesita un while, pero tal como lo has puesto tan solo devolverá el primer registro de lo que contenga (si solo es uno pues ya está... si son varios el resto los pierdes).  ¿El resultado de la consulta devuelve una columna llamada **'NOMBRE_ACA'**? ... Tampoco tengo muy claro que es **$academia**, no lo has puesto en la pregunta, quizas allí tienes el fallo.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con todo el pdf creado,  $academia es la variable que contiene la consulta del model.

Comment: Ya, pero en el model estás lanzando un CALL a algún procedimiento almacenado, que sigo sin saber si devuelve `NOMBRE_ACA` o no como columna. Si acaso haz un `print_r($row);die();`  después del `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($academia);` para ver exactamente que contiene o si esta vacio.

Comment: Este es el resultado del print 

Array ( [0] => 1 [ID_ACA] => 1 [1] => In Neh Kwan [NOMBRE_ACA] => In Neh Kwan [2] => Cartago [PROVINCIA_ACA] => Cartago [3] => 1 [ESTADO_ACA] => 1 [4] => 70000 [TOTAL_PAGAR_ACADEMIA] => 70000 )

Comment: Pues tiene buena pinta, se me escapa que puede estar ocurriendote, la verdad.  Teóricamente con ese resultado de **$row** no tendria que darte error la siguiente línea pues la columna **'NOMBRE_ACA'** aparece correctamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Por alguna razón no estaba tomando la variable $academia, por lo que he llamado nuevamente a la función **DatosAcademiaModel** con la variable $nombre y la he usado en el row. También cambié el **mysqli_fetch_array** por **mysqli_fetch_row** y usé la posición de ese array.

```
<?php
include_once "AcademiaModel.php";

require "../Template/plantillaPDF.php";


$id = $_GET['id'];

//function GenerarReportePDF(){

    $academia = DatosAcademiaModel($id);
    $estudiantes = DatosRegistroEstuModel();


    $pdf = new PDF("P", "mm", "Letter");
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    //$pdf -> SetMargins(20,20,20); Margenes de la hora left,top,right
    $pdf -> AddPage();

    $pdf -> SetFont("Arial", "B", 12);
    //$pdf -> Cell(95,5,"Nombre",1,0,"C");
    //$pdf -> Cell(95,5,"Total a pagar",1,0,"C");
    $pdf -> Ln(5);

    while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($academia)){
        $pdf -> SetFont("Arial", "", 12);
        $pdf -> Cell(95,5,"Nombre de la academia: " . $item['NOMBRE_ACA'],0,0,"C");
        $pdf -> Cell(95,5,"Monto total a pagar: " .$item['TOTAL_PAGAR_ACADEMIA'],0,0,"C"); 
        $pdf -> Ln(10);
    }
    $pdf -> SetFont("Arial", "B", 12);
    $pdf -> Cell(100,5,"Nombre",1,0,"C");
    $pdf -> Cell(30,5,"Cedula",1,0,"C");
    $pdf -> Cell(20,5,"Eventos",1,0,"C");
    $pdf -> Cell(40,5,"Monto a pagar",1,0,"C");
    $pdf -> Ln(5);

    while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($estudiantes)){
        $pdf -> SetFont("Arial", "", 9);
        $pdf -> Cell(100,5,$datos['NOMBRE_ATLETA'],1,0,"C");
        $pdf -> Cell(30,5,$datos['CEDULA_ATLETA'],1,0,"C"); 
        $pdf -> Cell(20,5,$datos['EVENTOS'],1,0,"C"); 
        $pdf -> Cell(40,5,$datos['MONTO_A_PAGAR'],1,0,"C"); 
        $pdf -> Ln(5);
    }


    $nombre = DatosAcademiaModel($id);

    if($row = mysqli_fetch_row($nombre)){
        $pdf -> Output("Reporte ".$row[1].".pdf", "D");
    } else {
        echo 'No hay datos';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Vale, ahora comprendo lo que te ocurria... Ya te habias **comido** el resultado en esta línea:  `while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($academia)){`  por lo tanto ya no quedaban más registros que leer (en cada mysqli_fetch_array que se hace el handle de la base de datos elimina un registro, y al hacer el while de todos pues eso, ya lo habias dejado vacio y después, al hacerlo de nuevo, era NULL pues no quedaban más registros)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario!